# After binding a datasource to a dataGridView new line GUI doesn't appear

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to use a `BindingList` as my data source, however before I bound it I got a line like this is my `dataGridView`:

[image]

Here I can add more rows to the table, however after I bound the `list` this is what appeared:

[image]

Hence I was wondering how to get this functionality back?

I am using this code to use the `bindingList` as the datasource:

```
data = new BindingList<Element>();
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
```

Comment: Have you tried dataGridView1.Invalidate() or dataGridView1.Refresh()?

Comment: Just worked it out I just had to set `AllowEdit` and `AllowNew` in the source for it to work